# Can't Connect to MySQL Using apoc.jdbc and Neo4J Community Edition 3.0.4

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

I'm using Neo4J Community Edition 3.0.4 for the Mac. Within the plugins folder I've got apoc and the mysql connector for Java.

I would like to connect to MySQL on localhost using JDBC.

I've created an alias in the .neo4j.conf file using.

```
apoc.jdbc.mysql_basemodel.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basemodel?user=fred&password=pw
```

In the browser I've tried to test the connection using:

```
CALL apoc.load.jdbc("mysql_basemodel","t_object") YIELD row
RETURN count(*);
```

but get the error

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.jdbc`: Caused by: > java.lang.RuntimeException: No apoc.jdbc.mysql_basemodel.url jdbc url specified

It's almost as if Neo4J is not reading the .neo4j.conf file with the alias defined.

If, however, I skip the alias and put the full connection string is I get the error:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.jdbc`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot execute SQL statement `SELECT * FROM t_object`.
>   Error:
>   No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basemodel?user=...

which seems to suggest that the mysql JDBC driver isn't found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to register the JDBC driver for MySQL:

```
CALL apoc.load.driver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Once you've registered the MySQL JDBC driver your statements using `apoc.load.jdbc` will make use of this this driver when connecting to MySQL.

More information available in the docs [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-use-cypher-to-connect-to-a-rbms-using-jdbc/).

Answer (score 0):

Download the mysql JDBC driver (e.g. from  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) and drop it into the `/plugins` folder - same location like apoc's jar file.

Comment: The JDBC driver is present - the cure / missing instruction was the registration of the driver as William Lyon pointed out.